# Connecting Yii 1.1.X app to MsSql with no named instance

Tags: sql-server, yii

I am trying to connect my yii application to ms sql server which has no named instance, just the default one, but i keep getting this error, "CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection" . Here is my connection string

```
'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'sqlsrv:Server=DGTSW00020US2;database=myDB', 
'username' => 'sa',                 
'password' => '*****',              
'charset' => 'utf8',                
'emulatePrepare' => false),
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your string to

```
'db'=>array('connectionString' => 'mssql:Server=DGTSW00020US2;database=myDB', 
'username' => 'sa',                 
'password' => '*****',              
'charset' => 'utf8',                
'emulatePrepare' => false),
```

(e.g. Change the

**sqlsrv**:Server=DGTSW00020US2;database=myDB

to

**mssql**:Server=DGTSW00020US2;database=myDB

)

Source: [Yii Frameowrk - Data Access Objects (DAO)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#establishing-database-connection)

Comment: Thank u very much [Rachel Ambler] for your answer, however I'm using the sqlsrv driver with php 5.4 which does not support mssql driver..your answer will work well with a lower version of php.

Answer (score 0):

Finally guys I manged to solve my problem,
I commented out this line ('emulatePrepare' => false ) and it worked properly.

Thank you